Micrometer Observation - adding metadata to an observation
I am working with Spring Observability and Micrometer. I am trying to capture some metadata for my spans, specifically the param keys and values.
I know I can use the @Observed annotation but it looks like it only captures lowCardinalityValues and I'm not sure if you can add in param values to them.
The only way I figured out how to capture the param values is to manually wrap the core logic in my service method in an Observation like this:
public List<Recipes> findRecipes(
            String type,
            List<UUID> ownerIds,
            Boolean includeOwner,
            Boolean includeTested,
            String sort,
            Integer limit
) {
    
        KeyValues lowCardinalityKeyValues = KeyValues.of(
                "type", String.valueOf(type),
                "includeOwner", String.valueOf(includeOwner),
                "includeTested", String.valueOf(includeTested),
                "sort", String.valueOf(sort),
                "limit", String.valueOf(limit)
        );

        return Observation.createNotStarted("test", observationRegistry)
                .contextualName("findRecipes")
                .lowCardinalityKeyValues(lowCardinalityKeyValues)
                .highCardinalityKeyValue("ownerIds", String.valueOf(ownerIds))
                .observe(() -> recipeDao.findRecipes(
                        type,
                        ownerIds,
                        includeTested,
                        sort,
                        limit
                ));
    }

It works, but there is a lot of manual work. Is there a better way to do this? Previously with Sleuth I was using @SpanTag and that used to work, but not any more.

Could you please open a new issue for this? We have something similar for metrics and spans (@MeterTag/@SpanTag) but not for Observations yet (no one asked), maybe we should. https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/new/choose
